# Plotting MYSQL Result in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database, datetime, plot

Please I need your assistance as I am not a python guru.

I am working on a design to log results in mysql server and afterwards, plot the results from the three inputs against time / day separately. I have logged the data but the plot is giving errors. This error is from the datetime function where i used datatype timestamp.

This is the actual program that I am using in Raspberry Pi on Python 2.7

```
import time 
import datetime 
import os
import MySQLdb as db

from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
=========================================================================

db_name = 'loggs'
conn = db.connect(user='cbpgg', passwd="rasp")
cur = conn.cursor()  #creates a database instance

temp = cur.execute("select Tempt from loggs.goxxy")
x = cur.execute("select datetime from loggs.goxxy")
curr = cur.execute("select Current from loggs.goxxy")
pres = cur.execute("select Pressure from loggs.goxxy")
array = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
x1 = np.array([datetime.datetime(2015,4,13,i,0) for i in range(24)]) #Daily plot
x2 = np.array([datetime.datetime(2015,4,i,3,0) for i in range(30)])#Monthly plot
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1,temp,'--', x1,pres,'-',x1,curr,'*')
plt.plot(x2,temp,'--', x2,pres,'-',x2,curr,'*')
plt.show()
conn.close()
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/pi/resp_tab.py", line 31, in  array = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") TypeError: must be string, not long

I think the error is on the np.array but cannot resolve it because I used:

```
select Substring(datetime, -6) as value from goxxy;
```

I trimmed part of the string in time get time in hours only and daily only from time and date respectively but the other parts were still not excluded.

Please, assist me to resolve this issue but if you do not understand the illustration, I will appreciate someone that could show me a sample program to plot a graph using the datetime data on the x-axis and how the time or date only used for the plot was extracted and converted from the string of datetime data logged into the server.

I appreciate your time. Cheers

Comment: Which Python - MySQL connector are you using?

Comment: It is a lot easier to help you if you post the full traceback (error message) along with your question

Comment: ah well ... first you have a syntax error `'--', x1` instead of `'--'.x1`...

Comment: then, when you do `plot(x, y)`, `x` and `y` must have the same length. I don't know the length of `aa`, `bb`, `cc` but `x1` and `x2` have different lengths, so clearly one of the two lines will not work

Comment: The lengths are all 600 presently for the x1, x2, pressure, current and tempt

Comment: This is the Trackback error message from the code:                         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/resp_tab.py", line 31, in <module>
    array = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
TypeError: must be string, not long

Comment: Hi, your Traceback above tells you that the problem is not with plotting - it's that when you call `datetime.datetime.strptime()`, the variable you are sending to it has type `long` and you should be passing it a `string`. Your variable `xx` is likely a timestamp - if you want it as a formatted string, consider using `datetime.fromtimestamp()` to get a `datetime` type and then `datetime.strftime`. For future reference - when adding a Traceback to a question, edit it into the actual post (rather than in a comment) and formatted it in some fixed width way - e.g. quoted code.